# Database won't connect in Somee

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web

I am using Somee free hosting, and I recently uploaded my asp web app. However, every time I am trying to perform an action related to the database, it returns an error: "Server Error in '/' Application. The network path was not found". I looked it up and found that this problem is caused because people didn't put the connection string, but I did. I suspect that it is something related to the web.config somehow, but I can't put my hand on the problem. This is my web config:

```
   <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database" connectionString="workstation id=DatabaseMDF.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=Eitan111;pwd=(removed);data source=DatabaseMDF.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=DatabaseMDF"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="HomePage.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And this is the code behind which causes the error:

```
public static bool IsExist(string fileName, string sql)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
        SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();   

        bool found =Convert.ToBoolean(data.Read());
        conn.Close();
        return found;         
    }
```

And this is the error:

> The network path was not found Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network
>   path was not found
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 41:         Line 42:         SqlConnection conn =
>   ConnectToDb(fileName); Line 43:         conn.Open(); Line 44:
>   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql,conn); Line 45:
>   SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
>
> Source File:
>   d:\dzhosts\localuser\eitan1112\www.GuitarTabs.somee.com\App_Code\Helper.cs
>   Line: 43

[When I looked up,:](https://forums.asp.net/t/1969146.aspx?Getting%20a%20Network%20path%20was%20not%20found%20when%20trying%20to%20open%20a%20database%20connection%20Why%20is%20that%20) I found this however it wan't helpful because he solved it by replacing files from 10 years ago which weren't up to date. I am using visual studio 2010.

Thanks in advance for any help.
P.S. I am still new so if there's a problem in my question structure, please respond kindly.

Comment: This is a [vendor support question](http://somee.com/DOKA/DoHelpTopics.aspx?docode=false&thnid=103)